# Printer says printing complete but doesn't print

Tags: drivers, usb, printing

I have an old Epson SX400 printer. It worked on my old ubuntu 20.04 laptop. Got a new laptop, same OS, but now the printer doesn't work. It works fine as a scanner, but when I try to print it tells me printing is complete without doing anything.

(Driver installation appeared to go fine, and I have rebooted both computer and printer several times).

I don't know if this is relevant, but I checked syslog when connecting the USB, and get the following:

```
May 13 10:29:36 sam-Apollo kernel: [ 2132.097742] usb-storage 3-3:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
May 13 10:29:36 sam-Apollo kernel: [ 2132.098013] scsi host0: usb-storage 3-3:1.2
May 13 10:29:36 sam-Apollo systemd[1]: Started Configure Plugged-In Printer.
May 13 10:29:36 sam-Apollo udev-configure-printer: add usb-003-010
May 13 10:29:36 sam-Apollo udev-configure-printer: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3
May 13 10:29:36 sam-Apollo udev-configure-printer: Device already handled
May 13 10:29:36 sam-Apollo systemd[1]: configure-printer@usb-003-010.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 13 10:29:36 sam-Apollo systemd[1]: configure-printer@usb-003-010.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 13 10:29:37 sam-Apollo kernel: [ 2133.120447] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     EPSON    Stylus Storage   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
```

After making sure the printer was selected as default, syslog shows something slightly different, although the problem persists.

```
May 13 11:51:47 sam-Apollo systemd[1]: Started Configure Plugged-In Printer.
May 13 11:51:47 sam-Apollo udev-configure-printer: add usb-003-004
May 13 11:51:47 sam-Apollo kernel: [  110.737617] usblp 3-3:1.1: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 4 if 1 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04B8 pid 0x084A
May 13 11:51:47 sam-Apollo kernel: [  110.737656] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
May 13 11:51:47 sam-Apollo kernel: [  110.738978] usb-storage 3-3:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
May 13 11:51:47 sam-Apollo kernel: [  110.739964] scsi host0: usb-storage 3-3:1.2
May 13 11:51:47 sam-Apollo kernel: [  110.740079] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
May 13 11:51:47 sam-Apollo kernel: [  110.742682] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
May 13 11:51:47 sam-Apollo udev-configure-printer: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3
May 13 11:51:47 sam-Apollo udev-configure-printer: MFG:EPSON MDL:Stylus SX400 SERN:- serial:4B4E5A593131323556
May 13 11:51:48 sam-Apollo kernel: [  111.751062] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     EPSON    Stylus Storage   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
May 13 11:51:48 sam-Apollo kernel: [  111.751250] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
May 13 11:51:49 sam-Apollo kernel: [  111.822671] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
May 13 11:51:53 sam-Apollo kernel: [  115.802611] usblp0: removed
May 13 11:51:53 sam-Apollo kernel: [  115.809621] usblp 3-3:1.1: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 4 if 1 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04B8 pid 0x084A
May 13 11:51:53 sam-Apollo /hpfax: [3701]: error: Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip
May 13 11:51:54 sam-Apollo udev-configure-printer: URI contains USB serial number
May 13 11:51:54 sam-Apollo udev-configure-printer: URI match: usb://EPSON/Stylus%20SX400?serial=4B4E5A593131323556&interface=1
May 13 11:51:54 sam-Apollo udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: usb://EPSON/Stylus%20SX400?serial=4B4E5A593131323556&interface=1, normalized: epson stylus sx400 serial 4b4e5a593131323556 interface 1
May 13 11:51:54 sam-Apollo udev-configure-printer: URI of print queue: usb://EPSON/Stylus%20SX400?serial=4B4E5A593131323556&interface=1, normalized: epson stylus sx400 serial 4b4e5a593131323556 interface 1
May 13 11:51:54 sam-Apollo udev-configure-printer: Queue ipp://localhost/printers/Stylus-SX400 has matching device URI
May 13 11:51:54 sam-Apollo systemd[1]: configure-printer@usb-003-004.service: Succeeded.
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Go into 'Settings' < 'Devices' < 'Printers'and make sure the Epsom printer is shown as default ( with a check against it ) If you have more than one printer shown - delete any you do not use.

Comment: Thanks. Gave that a try, but it didn't help.

Comment: Do you get the same exit-code after restarting the system?

Comment: No. I have added an edit with the syslog output after selecting default and restarting.

Comment: Reinstall hplip:

>>> sudo apt remove hplip

>>> sudo apt install hplip

and try again

Comment: Alas, no help..

Comment: @Sara hplip is for HP printers. This user has an Epson.

Comment: Indeed the error description says that the .hplip file is missing and Hplip stands for "The Hewlett-Packard Linux Imaging and Printing Project" 
and is not used only for HP printers but supports more than 1000 sort of printers@heynnema

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling after reinstalling hplip? If not, reinstall this time exclusively from terminal(not gui)

Comment: @Sara Installing the correct Epson printer driver solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a USB printer, more than likely the serial # has changed. The following line shows the serial #, and if you check your current printer properties, you'll see the serial # doesn't match.

```
May 13 11:51:54 sam-Apollo udev-configure-printer: URI match: usb://EPSON/Stylus%20SX400?serial=4B4E5A593131323556&interface=1
```

Just delete the printer, then re-add it, and you should be fine.

**Note**: You can purge hplip, as it's only for HP printers.

**Update #1:**

Install the Epson driver from:

https://epson.com/Support/wa00821

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Comment: I already added and removed the printer several times, I'm afraid.

Comment: @samfrances Do you dual-boot with Windows. If so, does the printer work there? What printer driver did you install? Where did you get it?

Comment: @samfrances See https://tutorialforlinux.com/2021/03/18/step-by-step-driver-epson-stylus-sx400-sx410-sx420w-ubuntu-installation/

Comment: No dual boot. The printer is an Epson SX400. The driver was the one that the printer settings found automatically. "Epson Stylus Scan 2500"

Comment: @samfrances That sounds like the wrong driver. Delete that printer definition. See http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule or https://epson.com/Support/wa00821

Comment: That worked. Thanks.

Comment: @samfrances Great news!